# RHEL jdk-8u20-linux-x64.tar.gz 1.8 acting like 32bit

Tags: java, 32bit-64bit, rhel6

I'm setting up a new machine. I did inadvertently install the 32-bit java first but I have blown that away and I have installed jdk-8u20-linux-x64.tar.gz (also used the RPM).

This machine has 132G or memory but I suspect I'm starting a 32 bit java app because it always runs out or memory at the same place regardless of -Xmx setting.

I do get a dump from java. It complains that I have 0 limit on core but most ulimit settings are unlimited or large.

The err.log suggests either lack of physical mem. or in 32 bit mode.  I can't believe the former, but cannot prove/disprove the latter.

The program manages and array of processes.  It chokes after invoking 12 java processes each of which immediately reads 2G of data into memory.

Here's proof of concept app:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class PrintProps {

public static void main(String[] args) {
for (String pname : System.getProperties().stringPropertyNames()) {
    System.out.println(String.format("Key:%30s  PropVal:%s", pname,         System.getProperty(pname)));
}
ArrayList<Process> alist = new ArrayList<Process>();

for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    String[] jargs = new String[]{
    "java",
    "-cp",
    "/usr/sup/jars/jpsgcs-pipe-pathing.jar",
    "jpsgcs.pipe.SGSPValue",
    "-d=/export/home/raja/SGS/CLL_MM_MBL/CLL_MM_DC/chrom9/6211-CLL_only_9.Loci.ped",
    "-p=/base/Human610Q/ld/chrom9/TF_H610Q_9.ld",
    String.format("-f=/tmp/6211/10K.%d",i)};

    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(jargs);
        pb.directory(new File("."));
        pb.inheritIO();
    System.out.println(String.format("pbuilder %d ", i ));
    try {
    alist.add(pb.start());
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
  }
}
```

TL/DR alert.  Sorry

Here is an hs_err.log

```
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Cannot create GC thread. Out of system resources.
# Possible reasons:
#   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
#   In 32 bit mode, the process size limit was hit
# Possible solutions:
#   Reduce memory load on the system
#   Increase physical memory or swap space
#   Check if swap backing store is full
#   Use 64 bit Java on a 64 bit OS
#   Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
#   Decrease number of Java threads
#   Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
#   Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
# This output file may be truncated or incomplete.
#
#  Out of Memory Error (gcTaskThread.cpp:48), pid=7938, tid=139841170798336
#
# JRE version:  (8.0_20-b26) (build )
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.20-b23 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007f2f48009000):  JavaThread "Unknown thread" [_thread_in_vm, id=7940, stack(0x00007f2f4f3f7000,0x00007f2f4f4f8000)]

Stack: [0x00007f2f4f3f7000,0x00007f2f4f4f8000],  sp=0x00007f2f4f4f6680,  free space=1021k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.so+0xa76cea]  VMError::report_and_die()+0x2ca
V  [libjvm.so+0x4e52fb]  report_vm_out_of_memory(char const*, int, unsigned long, VMErrorType, char const*)+0x8b
V  [libjvm.so+0x5afaff]  GCTaskThread::GCTaskThread(GCTaskManager*, unsigned int, unsigned int)+0x11f
V  [libjvm.so+0x5af068]  GCTaskManager::initialize()+0x2c8
V  [libjvm.so+0x90697b]  ParallelScavengeHeap::initialize()+0x32b
V  [libjvm.so+0xa44d0d]  Universe::initialize_heap()+0xfd
V  [libjvm.so+0xa4512f]  universe_init()+0x3f
V  [libjvm.so+0x612055]  init_globals()+0x65
V  [libjvm.so+0xa2acdd]  Threads::create_vm(JavaVMInitArgs*, bool*)+0x24d
V  [libjvm.so+0x6a9414]  JNI_CreateJavaVM+0x74
C  [libjli.so+0x736e]  JavaMain+0x9e
C  [libpthread.so.0+0x79d1]


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )

Other Threads:

=>0x00007f2f48009000 (exited) JavaThread "Unknown thread" [_thread_in_vm, id=7940, stack(0x00007f2f4f3f7000,0x00007f2f4f4f8000)]

VM state:not at safepoint (not fully initialized)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

GC Heap History (0 events):
No events

Deoptimization events (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (0 events):
No events

Events (0 events):
No events


Dynamic libraries:
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 23069232                           /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_20/bin/java
00600000-00601000 rw-p 00000000 fd:00 23069232                           /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_20/bin/java
01648000-01669000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
80200000-d4200000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
d4200000-580100000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
580100000-5aa100000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
5aa100000-800000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
32a4a00000-32a4a20000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 11010054                       /lib64/ld-2.12.so
32a4c1f000-32a4c20000 r--p 0001f000 fd:00 11010054                       /lib64/ld-2.12.so
32a4c20000-32a4c21000 rw-p 00020000 fd:00 11010054                       /lib64/ld-2.12.so
32a4c21000-32a4c22000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
32a4e00000-32a4e83000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 11010116                       /lib64/libm-2.12.so
32a4e83000-32a5082000 ---p 00083000 fd:00 11010116                       /lib64/libm-2.12.so
32a5082000-32a5083000 r--p 00082000 fd:00 11010116                       /lib64/libm-2.12.so
32a5083000-32a5084000 rw-p 00083000 fd:00 11010116                       /lib64/libm-2.12.so
32a5200000-32a538a000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 11010055                       /lib64/libc-2.12.so
32a538a000-32a558a000 ---p 0018a000 fd:00 11010055                       /lib64/libc-2.12.so
32a558a000-32a558e000 r--p 0018a000 fd:00 11010055                       /lib64/libc-2.12.so
32a558e000-32a558f000 rw-p 0018e000 fd:00 11010055                       /lib64/libc-2.12.so
32a558f000-32a5594000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
32a5600000-32a5617000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 11010062                       /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
32a5617000-32a5817000 ---p 00017000 fd:00 11010062                       /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
32a5817000-32a5818000 r--p 00017000 fd:00 11010062                       /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
32a5818000-32a5819000 rw-p 00018000 fd:00 11010062                       /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
32a5819000-32a581d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
32a5a00000-32a5a02000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 11010076                       /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
32a5a02000-32a5c02000 ---p 00002000 fd:00 11010076                       /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
32a5c02000-32a5c03000 r--p 00002000 fd:00 11010076                       /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
32a5c03000-32a5c04000 rw-p 00003000 fd:00 11010076                       /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
32a6200000-32a6207000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 11010066                       /lib64/librt-2.12.so
32a6207000-32a6406000 ---p 00007000 fd:00 11010066                       /lib64/librt-2.12.so
32a6406000-32a6407000 r--p 00006000 fd:00 11010066                       /lib64/librt-2.12.so
32a6407000-32a6408000 rw-p 00007000 fd:00 11010066                       /lib64/librt-2.12.so
32b5600000-32b5616000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 11010100                       /lib64/libnsl-2.12.so
32b5616000-32b5815000 ---p 00016000 fd:00 11010100                       /lib64/libnsl-2.12.so
32b5815000-32b5816000 r--p 00015000 fd:00 11010100                       /lib64/libnsl-2.12.so
32b5816000-32b5817000 rw-p 00016000 fd:00 11010100                       /lib64/libnsl-2.12.so
32b5817000-32b5819000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f2f32c00000-7f2f32ea0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f2f32ea0000-7f2f35400000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f2f35400000-7f2f356a0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f2f356a0000-7f2f37bff000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f2f37bff000-7f2f37d50000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f2f37d50000-7f2f38fff000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f2f38fff000-7f2f39000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f2f39000000-7f2f39270000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f2f39270000-7f2f48000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f2f48000000-7f2f48039000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f2f48039000-7f2f4c000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f2f4e129000-7f2f4e39e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f2f4e39e000-7f2f4e39f000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f2f4e39f000-7f2f4e49f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f2f4e49f000-7f2f4e4a0000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f2f4e4a0000-7f2f4e5aa000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f2f4e5aa000-7f2f4e960000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f2f4e960000-7f2f4e97a000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 23069413                   /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_20/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so
7f2f4e97a000-7f2f4eb7a000 ---p 0001a000 fd:00 23069413                   /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_20/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so
7f2f4eb7a000-7f2f4eb7b000 rw-p 0001a000 fd:00 23069413                   /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_20/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so
7f2f4eb7b000-7f2f4eb85000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 11010081                   /lib64/libnss_nis-2.12.so
7f2f4eb85000-7f2f4ed84000 ---p 0000a000 fd:00 11010081                   /lib64/libnss_nis-2.12.so
7f2f4ed84000-7f2f4ed85000 r--p 00009000 fd:00 11010081                   /lib64/libnss_nis-2.12.so
7f2f4ed85000-7f2f4ed86000 rw-p 0000a000 fd:00 11010081                   /lib64/libnss_nis-2.12.so
7f2f4ed86000-7f2f4ed92000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 11010077                   /lib64/libnss_files-2.12.so
7f2f4ed92000-7f2f4ef92000 ---p 0000c000 fd:00 11010077                   /lib64/libnss_files-2.12.so
7f2f4ef92000-7f2f4ef93000 r--p 0000c000 fd:00 11010077                   /lib64/libnss_files-2.12.so
7f2f4ef93000-7f2f4ef94000 rw-p 0000d000 fd:00 11010077                   /lib64/libnss_files-2.12.so
7f2f4efbc000-7f2f4efe6000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 23069378                   /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_20/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so
7f2f4efe6000-7f2f4f1e6000 ---p 0002a000 fd:00 23069378                   /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_20/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so
7f2f4f1e6000-7f2f4f1e8000 rw-p 0002a000 fd:00 23069378                   /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_20/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so
7f2f4f1e8000-7f2f4f1f5000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 23069412                   /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_20/jre/lib/amd64/libverify.so
7f2f4f1f5000-7f2f4f3f5000 ---p 0000d000 fd:00 23069412                   /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_20/jre/lib/amd64/libverify.so
7f2f4f3f5000-7f2f4f3f7000 rw-p 0000d000 fd:00 23069412                   /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_20/jre/lib/amd64/libverify.so
7f2f4f3f7000-7f2f4f3fa000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f2f4f3fa000-7f2f4f4f8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f2f4f4f8000-7f2f50162000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 23069417                   /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_20/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
7f2f50162000-7f2f50361000 ---p 00c6a000 fd:00 23069417                   /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_20/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
7f2f50361000-7f2f50438000 rw-p 00c69000 fd:00 23069417                   /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_20/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
7f2f50438000-7f2f5047d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f2f5047d000-7f2f50492000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 23069680                   /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_20/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
7f2f50492000-7f2f50691000 ---p 00015000 fd:00 23069680                   /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_20/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
7f2f50691000-7f2f50692000 rw-p 00014000 fd:00 23069680                   /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_20/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
7f2f50692000-7f2f50693000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f2f506ae000-7f2f506b1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f2f506b1000-7f2f506b9000 rw-s 00000000 fd:00 12583065                   /tmp/hsperfdata_rob/7938
7f2f506b9000-7f2f506ba000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f2f506ba000-7f2f506bb000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f2f506bb000-7f2f506bc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fff31e86000-7fff31e9b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fff31eb9000-7fff31eba000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]

VM Arguments:
java_command: jpsgcs.pipe.SGSPValue -b -d=/export/home/rob/SGS/CLL_MM_MBL/CLL_MM_DC/chrom9/6211-CLL_only_9.Loci.ped -p=/base/Human610Q/ld/chrom9/TF_H610Q_9.ld -n=400 -s=1 --dist=8
java_class_path (initial): /usr/sup/jars/jpsgcs-pipe-pathing.jar
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0
CLASSPATH=/usr/sup/jars/jpsgcs-pipe-pathing.jar
PATH=.:/usr/sup/apache-maven-3.1.1/bin:/usr/sup/groovy/bin:/home/work/toolshed/gradle-2.0/bin:/usr/sup/eclipse:/usr/sup/pgsql/bin:/export/home/rob/bin:/usr/sup/bin:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin
USERNAME=rob
SHELL=/bin/bash
DISPLAY=:0.0

Signal Handlers:
SIGSEGV: [libjvm.so+0xa77530], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGBUS: [libjvm.so+0xa77530], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGFPE: [libjvm.so+0x8e1d90], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGPIPE: [libjvm.so+0x8e1d90], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGXFSZ: [libjvm.so+0x8e1d90], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGILL: [libjvm.so+0x8e1d90], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGUSR1: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=00000000000000000000000000000000, sa_flags=none
SIGUSR2: [libjvm.so+0x8e35c0], sa_mask[0]=00100000000000000000000000000000, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGHUP: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=00000000000000000000000000000000, sa_flags=none
SIGINT: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=00000000000000000000000000000000, sa_flags=none
SIGTERM: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=00000000000000000000000000000000, sa_flags=none
SIGQUIT: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=00000000000000000000000000000000, sa_flags=none


---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS:Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)

uname:Linux 2.6.32-431.29.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Sun Jul 27 15:55:46 EDT 2014 x86_64
libc:glibc 2.12 NPTL 2.12 
rlimit: STACK 10240k, CORE 0k, NPROC 1024, NOFILE 4096, AS infinity
load average:6.35 1.57 0.69

/proc/meminfo:
MemTotal:       132108656 kB
MemFree:        109573200 kB
Buffers:           71664 kB
Cached:          2582360 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:         19304804 kB
Inactive:        1990228 kB
Active(anon):   18639784 kB
Inactive(anon):     7724 kB
Active(file):     665020 kB
Inactive(file):  1982504 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:       8208380 kB
SwapFree:        8208380 kB
Dirty:            138276 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:      18403024 kB
Mapped:           168804 kB
Shmem:              5968 kB
Slab:             276284 kB
SReclaimable:     137288 kB
SUnreclaim:       138996 kB
KernelStack:       14032 kB
PageTables:        77708 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    74262708 kB
Committed_AS:   71622560 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:      518808 kB
VmallocChunk:   34289913932 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:  16584704 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:       65536 kB
DirectMap2M:     4079616 kB
DirectMap1G:    130023424 kB


CPU:total 32 (8 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 62 stepping 4, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, aes, clmul, erms, ht, tsc, tscinvbit



Memory: 4k page, physical 132108656k(109565180k free), swap 8208380k(8208380k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.20-b23) for linux-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_20-b26), built on Jul 30 2014 13:13:52 by "java_re" with gcc 4.3.0 20080428 (Red Hat 4.3.0-8)

time: Tue Oct 14 16:15:03 2014
elapsed time: 0 seconds (0d 0h 0m 0s)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may have hit the user's OS process limit (which from my empirical studies includes *Java threads*).  Hitting this limit can manifest in an `OutOfMemoryError`.

On RHEL, there is:

```
/etc/security/limits.d/90-nproc.conf
```

... which contains the user limits.  [On RHEL6 (and CentOS6) "max user processes" is set to 1024 by default](https://serverfault.com/a/434734).

Try setting it to `unlimited`:

```
# Default limit for number of user's processes to prevent
# accidental fork bombs.
# See rhbz #432903 for reasoning.

*          soft    nproc     unlimited
root       soft    nproc     unlimited
```

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108603/do-changes-in-etc-security-limits-conf-require-a-reboot) suggests that you should reboot for those changes to take effect.

Comment: That seems to have done the trick. Quite puzzling since my previous machine has the same 1024 limit and does not have the same problem!?

Answer (score -1):

I also got the same hs_err_pid*.log when updated JRE from JRE-6u45 to JRE-8u20 (server distribution) on 64-bit linux OS.

I have test case to reproduce. When I run multiple instances of this test case,  on JRE-6u45 I never get "insufficient memory for JVM" or hs_err_pid*.log The same test case gives hs_err_pid*.log with insufficient memory on the same m/c.

Then I learnt I had installed server distribution of JRE-8u20 and JRE-6u45 which I had is of desktop version. To confirm this I installed desktop version of JRE-8u20 and no issues now.

But I dont understand the root cause - why the difference b/w server and desktop version. is there any memory limits?